# Conversão de valor vindo do banco de dados em valor monetário com erro

Tags: c#, cast

No banco de dados(`SQL`) tenho um campo chamado `Valor` que é um decimal e contém o seguinte valor: **21581** que seria **R$215,81**

Porém ao fazer o `casting` deste valor ele está retornando

```
$"{reader["valor"]:c}"
"R$ 21.581,00"
```

Comment: C#??? Dividir por 10, não?

Comment: @LS_dev não, por 100, obrigado pela dica.. foi um norte para a resolução

Answer (score 0):

A conversão está correta.

Para que o valor convertido seja **R$215,81**, deveria estar gravado na base como **215.81**